# Dynamic AND clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Within a stored proc ,I want to include an AND clause in a query only if a particular condition is satisfied.

```
INSERT INTO #firstResults   
 SELECT x, y, z  FROM ep  
 WHERE ep.proposedBy = @Id  
 AND ep.pId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT pId FROM #tempProj)
```

The 'AND' clause should join in only when the #tempProj is not empty.
What is the most elegant way to implement this?

I am on sql server 2008.
Since this would be repeated several times over the proc,I wish to avoid branching IF statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
AND (ep.pId IN (SELECT DISTINCT pId FROM #tempProj) 
                OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempProj) = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tempProj)
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #firstResults   
    SELECT x, y, z  FROM ep  
    WHERE ep.proposedBy = @Id  
    AND ep.pId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT pId FROM #tempProj)
 END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #firstResults   
    SELECT x, y, z  FROM ep  
    WHERE ep.proposedBy = @Id 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM #tempProj)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #firstResults   
 SELECT x, y, z  FROM ep  
 WHERE ep.proposedBy = @Id  
 AND ep.pId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT pId FROM #tempProj)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #firstResults   
 SELECT x, y, z  FROM ep  
 WHERE ep.proposedBy = @Id  
END
```